# Make child component re-render without sending useless props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm changing state inside of the parent component:

```
  this.setState({ langIndex: 0 });
```

The parent component re-renders correctly. But it's child do not re-render unless I pass the state from the parent as props to them:

```
  <LoginForm langIndex={this.state.langIndex} />
```

Now `langIndex` is useless inside of LoginForm but I need stuff to re-render inside of it nonetheless. Is there any 'clean' way of doing so ?

Comment: 2 questions: 1) why would you need the render if nothing changed? 2) whats wrong with passing "useless" prop if what you really want to do is forcing a render?

Comment: 1) In the parent I'm changing the language of the app so I need the change to be visible in its child components 2) I doesn't feel right and I would like to avoid that. Plus we are using Typescript so there is this prop in component which isn't used and can get confusing for other devs

Comment: Does the child component reflects this change in the UI? if so, shouldn't it "know" what `langIndex` was selected in the parent?

Comment: Sounds like you need to pass `langIndex` from the parent component down to a grandchild-component, where the first child does not "need" this prop. This is a classic case of "prop-drilling" and is usually solved by some kind of state management library, such as `redux` or `MobX`. Without some kind of state management, you are pretty much left with just prop-drilling.

Comment: @Sagivb.g Well that seems to be the problem. The child doesn't react to the changes of parent

Comment: @Chris I agree 100% but this project has been running long time and there is no state management tool. It would solve this problem in instance

Comment: @Chris That's misleading, state managers are not responsible for passing data to children, in fact the 2 you mentioned are not really `react` specific. you probably meant `react-redux` and `mobx-react` which are both using react `context` to bypass prop drilling.

Comment: @Sagivb.g So the only solution is to use context ?

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan If your problem is to pass the props several level down, then this is a classic use case for [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). I'm not sure i fully understand your problem to be honest.

Comment: @Sagivb.g I think you misunderstood. If you want to circumvent "prop-drilling", which is what OP seems to do by passing a state variable down the component tree through several components, you need a state management lib (or use Context if React v16+).

Comment: @Chris No need for a state management lib to do something react offers out of the box (since day 1 BTW, not only since react16)

Comment: @Sagivb.g I would never recommend the experimental context api which was before React 16. Also, I said "usually solved", not "must have" ;) But yes, React 16+ you can use Context.

Comment: @Chris Using these libraries meaning you ARE using "the experimental context api" because this is what they are using. :)

Comment: @Sagivb.g With that logic React is obsolete because it uses JavaScript "under the hood". Redux took an unstable feature and made it better. I don't know what you are trying to prove here...

Comment: @Chris I'm not trying to prove anything and sorry of you got offended. I wrote about this in more details in [this article](https://debuggr.io/redux-vs-react-context/).

Comment: @Sagivb.g not at all, I am just trying to understand what you are saying. Yes, redux has always used the context api, and yes, technically you "don't *need* it", but should you? You literally said "*No need for a state management lib to do something react offers out of the box since day 1*" which sounds like you advice *against* the use of any state library no matter the use-case. Please explain what you meant :)

Comment: @Chris What i meant is that `redux` is not enabling you to pass data, `react-redux` is. And you don't need a state manager to only pass data because this is not the purpose of a state manger. So advising someone to use a 3rd party library that meant to do `X` while the OP wants to do `Y` is misleading.

Comment: Since the question is tagged with `react`, I think it's implied that I mean react-redux to connect the redux store to components. You are also wrong that `react-redux` solves a problem `X` and Context a problem `Y`. I would say that the latter only solves a subset of what the former does (or can do), since it is a lib that builds on top of the existing context api (new or old).

Comment: @Chris Have you ever tried `redux` without `react-redux`? The core thing it is doing is to subscribe and unsubscribe to the store, which won't be exists without `redux` and the entire ceremony of creating an action, reducer and the actuall store. it also "provide" and "connects" to a context. I don't think this is relevant nor needed to someone who just wants to pass down data to children.

Comment: @Sagivb.g Let's just agree to disagree and move on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in one of your comments that you are using `i18next`:

There are [react bindings](https://react.i18next.com/) for `i18next` that enable re-rendering on language change if that is what you want. They work by subscribing to the i18next store and triggering a state change on language change.

You can use the `useTranslation` hook:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  // or const [t, i18n] = useTranslation();

  return <p>{t('my translated text')}</p>
}
```

or the `WithTranslation` HOC:

```
function MyComponent({ t, i18n }) {
  return <p>{t('my translated text')}</p>
}

export default withTranslation()(MyComponent);
```

Calling `i18n.changeLanguage()` will trigger a re-render.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that you need to pass data from a Parent to a grand child (or several levels down the tree) and you don't want to pass it through all levels (usually called as prop drilling), then you can use [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to skip levels

Here is a running example:

```js
const MyContext = React.createContext(null);

const Child = () => {
  const value = React.useContext(MyContext);
  return <div>{`in child... ${value}`}</div>;
};

const Parent = () => <Child />;

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={value}>
      <div>App</div>
      <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <Parent />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: With context I wouldn't have to pass any props ? Because the problem isn't passing props through multiple child components. The problem is that I have to pass any props at all to make the child re-render

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan What are the contents of your child and why do you want to force a re-render?

Comment: @trixn As comented above, I'm changing the language of the app in the parent (I18n) and I need this change to be reflected in the child

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan You are not providing enough information to give a definite answer. How do your components below that component know the current language? Is it stored in some kind of a global object outside of component state that react is not aware of?

Comment: If you need to rerender a child because the language changed... Then pass the language prop to the child, which is obviously not a "useless prop".

Comment: @trixn I'm just calling `i18next.changeLanguage(locale)` and setting the index in state. The language changes but only if i pass the props or when I navigate elsewhere in the app. I have always though that when you change the state in the parent the child components should also re-render. That is what is confusing to me

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan Okay so the child is actually using the language to translate some stings it renders? Why do you think it is irrelevant then? It makes no sense. If the language is relevant for the childs DOM representation it should receive the language as a prop.

Comment: Children are always re-render when parent is updated, when we say render we are not talking about painting the DOM but about triggering the diffing algorithm so react knows what to update. there is a case when a child won't re-render and that's if its implementing `shouldComponentUpdate`  or using `React.memo`

Comment: @trixn the child isn't using the language. `changeLanguage` is called in the parent as well as the `setState`. The parent has JSX element with text which changes language but the JSX with text inside the child does not change. Only time when it re-renders is when i pass the `langIndex` from the parent into it. But `langIndex` is not used and not needed in the child. This question is about how to avoid passing useless props to child to make it re-render

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan What does `changeLanguage` do? How are the translated strings determined without knowledge of the currently active language? How does the child know which text to render if it doesn't know the language? You are omitting relevant information to properly answer the question. Please show us the code of `LoginForm` and `changeLanguage`.

Comment: It globally changes which translation file should be used from my understanding. https://www.i18next.com/overview/api

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan Okay and how to your components receive the strings of the current translation file? Aren't you using the [react bindings](https://react.i18next.com/) of `i18next`? I assume it works by using react context.

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan In other words: What you want is all components that render translatable strings to re-render on language change. Is that correct? If so, you should use the `useTranslation` hook or the `withTranslation` HOC from the [`react-i18next`](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next) package. They subscribe to the translation store and trigger a state change on language change. Then you also don't need the `langIndex` in your parent at all.